# JavaScript Switch Case isn't working as expected

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, case

I am a beginner at best with JavaScript so this is likely an amateur mistake. For some reason when I run this code in js.node I always get the default case. The incoming data displays to the console just fine so I assume that the variable latestData is actually storing the incoming data. The console.log in each case is so that I know which case it is using, if any.

Any help is appreciated!

EDIT: Code modified as seen below, but I still have the same issue
I will share the arduino program and a screenshot of the serial monitor when I get home today if that helps.

```
var arDrone = require('ar-drone'); //Include the ar-drone library
var serialport = require('node-serialport'); //Include the serialport Library
var latestData = 0;

SerialPort = serialport.SerialPort, //Create local Instance

//Define the port and function to call
myPort = new SerialPort("/dev/ttyO3", {
    parser: serialport.parsers.readline("\r\n"), //Look for return and newline at the end of each packet. Serial.println() adds this
    baud: 9600
});

//Define what functions are called on each event
myPort.on('data', saveLatestData);
myPort.on('close', showPortClose);
myPort.on('error', showError);
myPort.on('open', showPortOpen);

//Callback functions for serial data events
function showPortOpen() {
   console.log('PORT OPEN');
}

function saveLatestData(data) {
   console.log(data);
   latestData = data;
}

function showPortClose() {
   console.log('PORT CLOSED');
}

function showError(error) {
   console.log('SERIAL PORT ERROR ' + error);
}


var client = arDrone.createClient();

//client.takeoff();  //Drone take off command, functional but removed for bench test

// Logic to read in sensor data from arduino and send flight commands to drone
switch(String.fromCharCode(latestData))
{
case 'X':
console.log('X IR');
client
    .after(1000, function() {
    this.clockwise(0.1);
  })
        .after(1000, function() {
        this.front(0.05);
  });
break;


case 'Y':
console.log('Y IR');
client
    .after(1000, function() {
    this.counterClockwise(0.1);
  })

       .after(1000, function() {
       this.front(0.05)
       });
break;

case 'Z':
console.log('Z IR');
client
    .after(1000, function() {
    this.back(0.05);
  })
        .after(1000, function() {
        this.clockwise(0.1)
    });
break;

case 'A':
console.log('A IR');
client
    .after(1000, function() {
    this.back(0.05);
  })
        .after(1000, function() {
        this.clockwise(0.1)
    });
break;

case 'N':
console.log('N IR');
client
    .after(1000, function() {
    this.front(0.05);
  }); 
break;

case 'L':
console.log('L IR');
client
    .after(1000, function() {
    this.clockwise(0.1);
  })
        .after(1000, function() {
        this.front(0.05);
  });
break;

case 'R':
console.log('R IR');
client
    .after(1000, function() {
    this.counterClockwise(0.1);
  })

       .after(1000, function() {
       this.front(0.05)
       });
break;

default:
console.log('DEFAULT CASE');
client
    .after(1000, function() {
    this.front(0.05)
  });
break;
}
```

Here is the arduino code that is sending serial data to the port that js.node is reading. Pretty simple

```
/*
description:
The sample code is used to measure distance by GP2Y0A02YK IR ranger sensor.
The information is then sent serially to Ar.Drone serial port tty03
VCC -- VCC
GND -- GND
Signal -- Analog 1
*/

/*int IRpinX = 1; // analog pin for reading the X IR sensor
int IRpinY = 3;  // analog pin for reading the Y IR sensor
int IRpinZ = 5;  // analog pin for reading the Z IR sensor
*/

bool X;  // set high when X IR sensor detects obstacle
bool Y;  // set high when Y IR sensor detects obstacle
bool Z;  // set high when Z IR sensor detects obstacle


void setup()
{
Serial.begin(9600); // start the serial port

//SET ANALOG PINS TO BE USED FOR IR SENSOR INPUT
pinMode(A1, INPUT); // X SENSOR
pinMode(A3, INPUT); // Y SENSOR
pinMode(A5, INPUT); // Z SENSOR


}
void loop()
{
float voltsX = analogRead(A1)*0.0048828125; // value from sensor (5/1024) - if running 3.3.volts then change 5 to 3.3
float voltsY = analogRead(A3)*0.0048828125;
float voltsZ = analogRead(A5)*0.0048828125;
float distanceX = 65*pow(voltsX, -1.10); // worked out from graph 65 = theretical distance / (1/volts);
float distanceY = 65*pow(voltsY, -1.10);
float distanceZ = 65*pow(voltsZ, -1.10);

/*print the distances for each sensor to verify in the serial monitor
Used for initial testing
Serial.print("X = ");
Serial.println(voltsX);
Serial.print("Y = ");
Serial.println(voltsY);
Serial.print("Z = ");
Serial.println(voltsZ);*/

/*statements compare distance calculation to a static range and 
set a bit high for each sensor that detects an obstacle
May change to compare voltage as it seemed more stable*/ 

if (distanceX <=100) // check for obstacle in X direction
{
  X = HIGH;
}
else X = LOW;

if (distanceY <=100) // check for obstacle in Y direction
{
  Y = HIGH;
}
else Y = LOW;

if (distanceZ <=100) // check for obstacle in Z direction
{
  Z = HIGH;
}
else Z = LOW;

// Obstacle detected at X sensor only
if (X == HIGH && Y == LOW && Z == LOW)
{
Serial.println('X'); // Transmit character X in hex over serial port
}

// Obstacle detected at Y sensor only
if (X == LOW && Y == HIGH && Z == LOW)
{
Serial.println('Y'); // Transmit character Y in hex over serial port
}

// Obstacle detected at Z sensor only
if (X == LOW && Y == LOW && Z == HIGH)
{
Serial.println('Z'); // Transmit character Z in hex over serial port
}

// Obstacle detected at X and Y sensors only
if (X == HIGH && Y == HIGH && Z == LOW)
{
Serial.println('Z'); // Transmit character Z in hex over serial port
}                    // Not sure what to do in this condition. Turn instead?

// Obstacle detected at X and Z sensors only
if (X == HIGH && Y == LOW && Z == HIGH)
{
Serial.println('R'); // Transmit character R in hex over serial port
}                    // Rotate drone clockwise

// Obstacle detected at Y and Z sensors only
if (X == LOW && Y == HIGH && Z == HIGH)
{
Serial.println('L'); // Transmit character L in hex over serial port
}                    // Rotate drone counterclockwise

// Obstacle detected at X, Y and Z sensors
if (X == HIGH && Y == HIGH && Z == HIGH)
{
Serial.println('A'); // Transmit character L in hex over serial port
}                    // Rotate drone counterclockwise

// No Obstacle Detected
if (X == LOW && Y == LOW && Z == LOW)
{
Serial.println('N'); // Transmit character N over serial port
}                    // Hover in place


delay(100); // wait time in mS used to slow data send interval for testing

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You get the `default` all the time because you do not have any [`break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break) statements. If you do not include break the code will execute all the other cases below it.

```
case 'X':
    console.log('X IR');
    client
        .after(1000, function() {
            this.clockwise(0.1);
        })
        .after(1000, function() {
            this.front(0.05);
        });
    break; //You are missing this on every case
```

---

Other issue is the fact that the code is inline JavaScript that has thre swicth it is only going to run when the JavaScript is loaded and the default value for `var latestData = 0;` will be read and that will hit the default case. You need to set that in some sort of function and trigger it.

Comment: Thank You! I will add the break statements tomorrow and let you know.

Comment: Break statements added, but no change in operation.

Comment: Other issue is the fact that it ill not update when the variable changes so it is only going to use the default value when the code initially runs.

Comment: Can i add the switch code to the function saveLatestData(data) to have it run whenever data is received? Thank you for your help!

Comment: I added the switch statement within the function saveLatestData and it seems to work! I will have to connect up the drone and make sure the movement commands do what I want, but the console is showing that each case is being executed when it should!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that `latestData` contains integer code. But `'A'` in JavaScript is a string literal. That's why your case does not work, `65 != 'A'` in JS. You should use `String.fromCharCode(int)` to convert character code to string:

```
switch(String.fromCharCode(latestData)) {
  case 'A': ...; break;
  case 'B': ...; break;
}
```

Comment: and add `break;` to each case statement, otherwise it will go trough default statement anyway

Comment: The data that is being received is transmitted from an arduino using serial.println() to send the characters as ASCII text.  That could very well be part of the issue. Thanks!

Comment: What `typeof latestData` will give you? If it is a string then you probably need to get first character as string: `latestData[0]`

Comment: I'm not sure what you want me to do with "typeof latestData" ? And which instance of latestData do you think may need the brackets?